# Facebook Graph API 1.0 Deprecation

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have been been following the announcements surrounding F8 and I found this change log:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog

I am just wondering, if I understand this correctly ....

Does this change log mean that the graph API endpoints such as /me/friends, etc. will stop working on 4/15/2015 when version 1.0 of the API is turned off, or is Facebook going to be  removing the functionality sooner?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

/me/friends is available in API v2.0 too so it will not be removed. The change is that /me/friends don't return all friends in v2.0, it only return friends that are using the app.

You can start using v2.0 now by doing /v2.0/me/friends . If you specify /v1.0/me/friends or no version at all like /me/friends that will call v1.0 until 4/30/2015. At 4/30/2015 calling /v1.0/me/friends and /me/friends will be the same as calling /v2.0/me/friends

And if your app was created after 4/30/2014 you are not able to use v1.0 at all.

Comment: and just so I understand,when you are saying " If you specify /v1.0/me/friends or no version at all like /me/friends that will call v1.0 until 4/30/2015.", you mean it will call and continue to return user friends until 4/2015?

Comment: If you app was created before 4/30/2014 yes then you can use API v1.0. And as I said in my answer. Even after it will return friends.

Comment: thanks for clearing that up - one more question - does versioning affect the facebook connect dialogue - do apps that still have access to v1 create facebook connects that do not give users the ability to remove specific data requests (likes,etc)

Comment: Yes versioning effect the connect dialogue.

Answer (score 0):

Friend list is no longer part of the default permission set and has its own permission. Asking for access to a person's friend list is now a separate permission that your app MUST request. The new permission is called user_friends. So, you need to remind that as well.